# From where does positive semidefinite thing came

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite, linear-matrix-inequality

From Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/):

[image]

As I understand, all $x_i$ are scalar. So, when it says $A(x) \preceq B$, it should mean elementwise inequality. Thus for $B - A(x)$ matrix, all elements should be $\geq 0$. From where does positive semidefinite came?

Edit: Thanks for clarification

Comment: No, it is **not** elementwise inequality. Rather, stating that $B - A(x) \succeq 0$ is equivalent to stating that [all $2^m - 1$ principal minors are nonnegative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion).

Comment: Boyd and Vandenberghe explain the meaning of this generalized inequality earlier in the book. The statement that $B - A(x) \succeq 0$ means that $A - B(x)$ is a positive semidefinite matrix.